# how to use git for merge unrelated branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, project

I used to made projects that involves pcb boards design and firmware development, for same product. My question is, how should I use git, to work on two branches 'PCB' and 'FIRM', and eventualy merge them on a RELEASE1.0 commit that indicates these tag do work? For example, I work on pcb for a week, then I made the board, in between I do some firm dev, when the board cames, I test it and if it works I merge PCB with FIRM in the first RELEASE, so then I found some mistake in the PCB, so I fix it and made it again, but the last firm won't be backward compatible, so when the new board cames I have to merge the new firm, and so on.. My problem is that the files are totally unrelated but I wanna have a picture of the all stuff when it works, so If I do a simple merge, it fails 'cose there are not any file similar from FIRM to PCB.. how should you maintain these kind of projects? Actually I've more than FIRM and PCB, I also have, SOFT, 3Ddesign, Bootloaders, and others unrelated files but related to the product... so I really wana a pictures when all that stuff converge and works...thanks in advance for your suggestions.. Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have many branches, include 2 branches `foo` and `bar` (`foo` and `bar` are unrelated directly. Reality, all random two branches couple are related directly/indirectly).

Then you want merge `bar` to `foo`:

```
git checkout foo
git merge bar
git add -A .
git push
```

or other solution (rebase by 3-ways merge)

```
git checkout foo
git rebase bar
git checkout bar
```